# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol after moving functions to another header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I had two array templates in one of my header files, everything worked well. Then I thought, I'd better get some more pedantism into my code, so I moved them all into another header file, mostly just for them (and for another function, that wants to use one of them). And then I got LNK2019 error every time I used functions from these templates in other header files.

Since everything was good before I pasted my code elsewhere, I assume the code is okay, it's just my lack of understanding. Basically, the question is: why do I get a linker error when I moved my function to another header file?

Here is an example of one of my errors:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: char __thiscall C2DArray::Get(int,int)" (?Get@?$C2DArray@D@@QAEDHH@Z) referenced in function "public: char __thiscall SGame::GetRecordOutput(int,int)" (?GetRecordOutput@SGame@@QAEDHH@Z) Mastermind  C:\Users\Master\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Mastermind\Mastermind\Menu.obj    1

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 if it matters.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: In simple cases (which I think you have) the error means some compilation unit has seen the declaration and hasn't seen the definition but has called that function.  I assume some other compilation unit has seen the definition as `inline`.  When an `inline` function is defined separately from its declaration, it is OK for a module to see the declaration without definition, only if that module doesn't use that function.  It sometimes works to call a function defined `inline` only in another module.  But even when it works, it isn't correct C++.

Comment: Specifically, a module instantiating `SGame::GetRecordOutput` has seen the declaration but not definition of `C2DArray::Get` **and** any module that did see the definition of `C2DArray::Get` saw it as `inline`.  That combination of facts adds up to incorrect code and must be fixed (typically by including the definition of `C2DArray::Get` where needed).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply. As it seems, I have resolved my problem. The cause was the class templats, which were not specialized (and had to be). All I had to do is include what types of these templates I wanted. Sorry for posting before doing more extensive research.